# Photo resize. Client-side or server-side?

Tags: resize, client, photo

I create a photo-gallery site. I want an each photo to have 3 or 4 instances with different sizes (including original photo). 
Is better to resize a photo on client-side (using Flash or HTML5) and upload all the instances of this photo to a server separately? Or it's better to upload a photo to a server only one time, but resize it using server resources (for example GD)?
What would be your suggestions?
Also it's interesting to know, how does big sites do this work? For example 500px.com (this site for each photo creates 4 instances and all works fast enough) or Facebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several schools of thought on this topic, it really comes down to how many images you have an how likely it is that the images will be viewed more than once.  It is most common for all of the image sizes to be created using a tool like Adobe Photoshop, GIMP, Sizzlepig or GD (locally or on A server, not necessarily the web server) then upload all the assets to the server.

Resizing before you host the image takes some of the strain off of the end-user's web browser and more importantly reduces the amount of bandwidth required to host the site (especially useful when you are running a large site and paying per GB transferred)

To answer your part about really big sites, some do image scaling ahead of time, others do it on the fly, but typically it's done server side.